# Set Id to Other column in same table while doing insertQuery

Tags: mysql, hibernate

Hi I have a MYSQL table like

```
PART{
 part_id :long,Auto Increment
 parent_part_id :long
 root_part_id :long
}
```

I need to do Insert Query on this table where root_part_id should get value of part_id .
In Other cases I know the parent and root part Id . but while doing insertion of root part i need this query. I know there is a option that I should fire a update query after this insert query but I need a solution in a single Query.

Comment: Can you give examples of what you want, I am lost in your long text explanations

Comment: When I do insert query it should set root_part_id as generated part_id

Answer (score 1):

You can use a trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `before_insert_PART`
BEFORE INSERT ON `PART` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
        SET NEW.root_part_id = NEW.part_id;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

PS, better use only small characters for your table names. It can lead to OS incompatibilities, on Linux names are case sensitive, and on Windows - not.